# Sorting in Access Database

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm having problem on query using Access database where I need to sort the data base on estimate hours. Below is the data

- Application     Hours
- App1              2
- App2              5
- App3              4
- App4            NuLL
- App5            NuLL

The query is joint of two table:-

```
SELECT application, sum(hours) from (SELECT DISTINCT application, hours, id 
FROM tbl_a RIGHT OUTER JOIN tbl_b ON tbl_a.id = tbl_b.id WHERE project_key = 5)
GROUP BY application
```

Problem :- When I tried to sort based on the Hours,I'm facing problem where it requires me to enter parameters before it can proceed.

Please advise

Comment: What parameter is it asking for? I recreated your example and got no errors.  Perhaps typo in your SQL query?

Comment: It's asking to enter the Hours

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
SORT BY sum(hours)
```

Comment: I'll laugh if it's because `hours` is an SQL keyword and Access doesn't realize it's used as a column name.

Comment: I just used Hours in the question but in real i'm using other

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to try the Nz Function in your sum.  Something similar to SUM(Nz(hours, 0)).  That will make your Nulls Zeros in your query.

For more information on the NZ function in MS Access check out this link: [Nz Function - Access](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/nz-function-HA001228890.aspx)